# Construct object from config file in C++

Tags: c++, toml

I have a toml file that I would like to convert to an instance of a class.

```
[Person]
Name = "Foo Bar"
BirthDay = "1979-05-27"
```

into an instance of the class:

```
class Person {
public:
std::string Name;
std::string BirthDay;
}
```

I can't image I am the first one to try this so I was wondering if there is a standard solution for this?

Comment: It's called serialization. You can create a factory function like `Person makePerson(std::string cfgFilename);`, or add a `Person::Person(std::string cfgFilename)` that accepts filename, or a stream. For toml parsing just use whatever, e.g. [some library](https://github.com/ToruNiina/toml11) that pops out as 1st google result when you ask for toml parsing.

Comment: If you follow the `toml` tag to its [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/toml/info) there's a link to its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) that contains further links to [the TOML wiki](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/wiki) which links to [implementations](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/wiki#implementations) you could check out and try.

Comment: @JasonLiam I understand, that is why I want an instance of the class that I have created myself.

Comment: @pptaszni I should have mentioned that I have a lot of these classes in the TOML file. I would like to avoid having to type it out for every class. So I want to avoid typing : 'person.Name = parseTOML("Name").value(); '

Comment: If it was possible and C++ had [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming), should the TOML field `Name` match the `Name` member of the object? What about classes with a `the_name_` variable? Or other variants which doesn't exactly match `Name` in the TOML file? There's just no way to automate this. At least not without writing a lot of code.

Comment: You can load your file into a suitable container, then iterate over this container and generate your classes. What did you try so far ? What part are you struggling on ? What issue did you encounter ?

Comment: @Fareanor How would I set members from a container?

Comment: By iterating over it, and for each element, you create the corresponding object. Example: if you use a map<string, map<string, string>> which semantically would mean map<class_name, map<parameter, value>>, each element of the outer map corresponds to an object. You iterate over the outer map, and you get what class to instantiate from the key, and the parameters to use from the value (the inner map).

Comment: FWIW the readme says "Because TOML is explicitly intended as a configuration file format, parsing it is easy, but it is not intended for serializing arbitrary data structures".

Answer (score 1):

C++ is multi-paradigm language. If you are looking for OO way, it is usually done with 2 steps:

1. Create object instance of specific type inherited from base based by it's name.

- This step is usually done using programming pattern [Factory](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/30138/factory-pattern) or [Factory Method](https://hackernoon.com/desing-patterns-exploring-factory-method-in-modern-c-hi1h3uvw)

2. Let object read it's data

- After object of proper type created, virtual method of the object is called that reads (deserializes) itself from data.

Both steps can be implemented manually or using libraries. Details would be specific on the way and what particular library you choose.

In some situations (for example you do not control implementation of classes you need to create/deserialize) you may want to create a parallel hierarchy of creater/reader classes, which can be created/accessed by target class name and have knowledge on how to create and deserialize (called proper constructor perhaps) of target classes.

Comment: Calling "default construct then deserialize mutably" the "OO way" is a bit of a stretch. That's a very C++ way of thinking about things. If I was writing Ruby, for instance, my deserializer function would almost certainly be a class function that constructs an object which is correct from the start.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo "If I was writing Ruby" sure, but question is about C++